# AttributeError: module 'posixpath' has no attribute 'joint'

Tags: ros2, python3, ros-foxy

I am trying to develop a simple bot using ROS 2. I created a package called my_rover. when I give

```
colcon build --packages-select my_rover
```

it gives this error which i cannot understand..

```
Starting >>> my_rover
Traceback (most recent call last):1.7s]
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 215, in run_setup
    exec(f.read(), g)
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'posixpath' has no attribute 'joint'
--- stderr: my_rover                   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/executor/__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/task/__init__.py", line 93, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_ros/task/ament_python/build.py", line 51, in build
    setup_py_data = get_setup_data(self.context.pkg, env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/task/python/__init__.py", line 20, in get_setup_data
    return dict(pkg.metadata[key](env))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_ros/package_augmentation/ros_ament_python.py", line 57, in getter
    return get_setup_information(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_python_setup_py/package_identification/python_setup_py.py", line 241, in get_setup_information
    _setup_information_cache[hashable_env] = _get_setup_information(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_python_setup_py/package_identification/python_setup_py.py", line 288, in _get_setup_information
    result = subprocess.run(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-c', 'import sys;from contextlib import suppress;exec("with suppress(ImportError):    from setuptools.extern.packaging.specifiers    import SpecifierSet");exec("with suppress(ImportError):    from packaging.specifiers import SpecifierSet");from distutils.core import run_setup;dist = run_setup(    \'setup.py\', script_args=(\'--dry-run\',), stop_after=\'config\');skip_keys = (\'cmdclass\', \'distclass\', \'ext_modules\', \'metadata\');data = {    key: value for key, value in dist.__dict__.items()     if (        not key.startswith(\'_\') and         not callable(value) and         key not in skip_keys and         key not in dist.display_option_names    )};data[\'metadata\'] = {    k: v for k, v in dist.metadata.__dict__.items()     if k not in (\'license_files\', \'provides_extras\')};sys.stdout.buffer.write(repr(data).encode(\'utf-8\'))']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
---
Failed   <<< my_rover [1.91s, exited with code 1]
                                
Summary: 0 packages finished [3.25s]
  1 package failed: my_rover
  1 package had stderr output: my_rover
Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-c', 'import sys;from contextlib import suppress;exec("with suppress(ImportError):    from setuptools.extern.packaging.specifiers    import SpecifierSet");exec("with suppress(ImportError):    from packaging.specifiers import SpecifierSet");from distutils.core import run_setup;dist = run_setup(    \'setup.py\', script_args=(\'--dry-run\',), stop_after=\'config\');skip_keys = (\'cmdclass\', \'distclass\', \'ext_modules\', \'metadata\');data = {    key: value for key, value in dist.__dict__.items()     if (        not key.startswith(\'_\') and         not callable(value) and         key not in skip_keys and         key not in dist.display_option_names    )};data[\'metadata\'] = {    k: v for k, v in dist.metadata.__dict__.items()     if k not in (\'license_files\', \'provides_extras\')};sys.stdout.buffer.write(repr(data).encode(\'utf-8\'))']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I have `python` version - 3.8.10 in my machine. How can I resolve this one?

In my_rover package I have these below files

`rover.urdf`

```
<?xml version= "1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name  = "my_rover">

    <link name="chassis">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.75 0.4 0.15" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="Orange">
                <color rgba="1.0 0.3 0.1 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.75 0.4 0.15" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="2"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.04" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.17" iyz="0.0" izz="0.25"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name="front_right_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://my_rover/meshes/right_tire.stl" scale = "0.005 0.005 0.005"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="Red">
                <color rgba="1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.18"/>
            </geometry>
            <contact_coefficients mu = "1" kp = "1e+13" kd = "1.0"/>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="2"/>
            <inertia ixx="1e-3" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1e-3" iyz="0.0" izz="1e-3"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="front_right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="0.2 0.24 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <parent link="chassis"/>
        <child link="front_right_wheel"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 0.0"/>
  </joint>

    <link name="front_left_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://my_rover/meshes/left_tire.stl" scale = "0.005 0.005 0.005"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="Red">
                <color rgba="1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.18"/>
            </geometry>
            <contact_coefficients mu = "1" kp = "1e+13" kd = "1.0"/>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="2"/>
            <inertia ixx="1e-3" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1e-3" iyz="0.0" izz="1e-3"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="front_left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="0.2 -0.24 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <parent link="chassis"/>
        <child link="front_left_wheel"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 0.0"/>
  </joint>

    <link name="back_right_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://my_rover/meshes/right_tire.stl" scale = "0.005 0.005 0.005"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="Red">
                <color rgba="1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.18"/>
            </geometry>
            <contact_coefficients mu = "1" kp = "1e+13" kd = "1.0"/>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="2"/>
            <inertia ixx="1e-3" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1e-3" iyz="0.0" izz="1e-3"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="back_right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="-0.2 0.24 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <parent link="chassis"/>
        <child link="back_right_wheel"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 0.0"/>
  </joint>

      <link name="back_left_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://my_rover/meshes/left_tire.stl" scale = "0.005 0.005 0.005"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="Red">
                <color rgba="1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.18"/>
            </geometry>
            <contact_coefficients mu = "1" kp = "1e+13" kd = "1.0"/>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="2"/>
            <inertia ixx="1e-3" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1e-3" iyz="0.0" izz="1e-3"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="back_left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="-0.2 -0.24 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <parent link="chassis"/>
        <child link="back_left_wheel"/>
        <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 0.0"/>
  </joint>

    <link name="camera">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.010 0.05 0.05"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="blue">
                <color rgba="0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.010 0.05 0.05"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.5" />
            <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0.0" ixz="0" 
            iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01" />        
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="chassis"/>
        <child link="camera"/>
        <origin xyz="0.375 0.0 0.15" rpy="0.0 0.0 3.14"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="lidar">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://my_rover/meshes/lds.stl" scale="0.002 0.002 0.002"/>            </geometry>
            <material name="LightGrey">
                <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.08" length="0.1"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.5"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0.0" izz="0.01"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="lodar_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="chassis"/>
        <child link="lidar"/>
        <origin xyz="0.2 0 0.25" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </joint>
</robot>
```

This my `1_rviz.lauunch.py` file

```
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    package_dir = get_package_share_directory('mr_rover')
    urdf = os.path.join(package_dir,'rover.urdf')

    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='robot_state_publisher',
            executable='robot_state_publisher',
            name='robot_state_publisher',
            output='screen',
            arguments=[urdf]),
        Node(
            package='joint_state_publisher_gui',
            executable='joint_state_publisher_gui',
            name='joint_state_publisher_gui',
            arguments=[urdf]),

        Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        output='screen'),
        

    ])
```

These are the two files I added after the package created.

And this is `setup.py` file

```
from setuptools import setup
import os
from glob import glob
package_name = 'my_rover'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
        
        (os.path.joint('share', package_name), glob('launch/*.py')),
        (os.path.joint('share', package_name), glob('urdf/*')),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='vasanth',
    maintainer_email='email@example.com',
    description='TODO: Package description',
    license='TODO: License declaration',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
        ],
    },
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! I tried correcting the format of the error but couldn't. Please edit your question and use the "Code Sample" icon shown using `{}` markers. Thank you for your kind cooperation.

Comment: done. I modified the question using {} markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that:

```
AttributeError: module 'posixpath' has no attribute 'joint'
```

`posixpath` is a part of the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library. This error comes up when you attempt to access an attribute of a class or import that does not exist: in this case, you've done something like this:

```
p = Path('./path/to/something')
p.joint
```

`joint` is not a valid attribute to ask from `Path`, and so the error is presented.

You are likely aiming to load the *contents* of a file at a path, but your code is actually only accessing the path. It's impossible to say exactly without seeing any code or your configuration, but you should take a closer look at how you are returning files: you likely want to return their parsed contents, but you're instead passing simply their path.

EDIT now that the setup.py has been provided:

The problem is in your setup.py, here:

```
os.path.joint('share', package_name)
```

and right below it:

```
os.path.joint('share', package_name)
```

Notice that you are calling the `path` module from `os`, and then you're expecting it to have the attribute `joint`. `path`, which in this case is `posixpath` because you're on a POSIX-compliant system, does not have that attribute.

In short, the `module 'posixpath' has no attribute called 'joint'`.

Perhaps you meant to call `os.path.join()` (no t) to *join* the paths?

Comment: i updated the question with the files i created in my_rover package. Honestly, i don't know which file you are mentioning. So, can you enlighten me more?

Comment: To help you guys understand what my package contains i added setup.py file in the question.

Comment: @Vasanth I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @cst0 for your insight. I should have checked the code at first, rather than focusing on only the error part. It works finally.